# How to set up eclipse for java me and android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Ive downloaded eclipse classic (3.7.1) today to set up an android development environment.
I also wanted to set up a java mobile dev env with java me 3.0 sdk. 
The thing is i dont want to download another eclipse for the java part, so am asking what should i download to add up to my "eclipse classic" install so that i can work on java mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

did you even try looking for an eclipse plugin? perhaps there is 'EclipseME'.
google be my guide anyone?

update your install via these instructions

http://eclipseme.org/docs/installEclipseME.html